# How to access state variable inside function if the function has variable with the same name?

Tags: solidity

I know it is not a good practice to have a function parameter with exactly the same name as a state variable, I simply ask this out of curiosity.

With some experiment, I found that the code below will work

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MyContract {
    uint256 public publicUint256;

    constructor() {
        publicUint256 = 100;
    }

    // test access state variable by this.xxx inside function
    function accessStateVariable(uint256 publicUint256) public {
        console.log("publicUint256", publicUint256);
        console.log("this.publicUint256()", this.publicUint256()); // this gives 100
        console.log(
            "this.publicUint256() + publicUint256",
            this.publicUint256() + publicUint256
        );
    }
}
```

Which means it is possible to access state variable inside function by doing `this.variable()`.

And the question I have is:

1. what's the difference between `this.variable()` vs `variable`?
2. although I can access value by doing `this.variable()` inside the function, but I cannot modify its value, anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your variable has a `public` visibility modifier, Solidity compiler also creates an [autogenerated getter function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions).

You can set/get the variable's value from within your contract and its child contracts. But from outside of the contract, the value is only readable using the getter function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    // external contracts can only read the value
    // using the autogenerated getter function
    uint256 public publicUint256;
}

contract MyChildContract is MyContract {
    // derived contracts can both get and set the value

    function setValue(uint256 _value) external {
        publicUint256 = _value;
    }

    function getValue() external view returns (uint256) {
        return publicUint256;
    }

    function getValue2() external view returns (uint256) {
        return this.publicUint256();
    }
}
```